# If there is only one actor(client) in a system, what architecture should I use?

Tags: oop, architecture, software-design

I'm preparing for the finals. I'm wondering what architecture I should use if I was told the following:

***only one actor(librarian) is involved in the interaction with the system and he is responsible to initiate all the use cases of the system. System also does not store the information about Library staff and single user, the librarian is supposed to manage members and books in the system.***

The choices are layered/Client-server/both. Someone told me that if there is only one actor then we do not use the client server architecture; but I'm confused if that was the case, why that's the case?

Also, what does the system not saving information have to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't thing having a single actor has anything to do with the system architecture in terms of layered or client/server.

the librarian uses the system to manage library members and books, so lets assume there are use cases to add a new book to the library, loan a book, add a new member, view lists of books and members, search, etc.

the librarian surely uses some client (doesn't matter if it's a web app or desktop app) that communicates with a server to get data for the librarian, and send his commands back to the server.

the server works with some DB (mySql, local files, mongoDB, whatever) to store the data.

I would assume for this kind of app to use n-tiers architecture. any app the has some client, some business logic, and data is probably 3-tiers at least.

the client renders data for the user, and submits his commands to the business logic tier. the business logic validates, processes, and writes/reads data from the data layer, which in turn communicates with a data store.

seems like you have at least a simple N-tier (or layered) application here. see [here](https://www.guru99.com/n-tier-architecture-system-concepts-tips.html) for a short and clear description of this subject.

regarding the "what does the system not saving information have to do with this?", I think it relates to "System also does not store the information about Library staff and single user" - meaning library staff management is not in the scope of the app, only books & members management.